# ArcGIS REST API - Adding related records when using addFeatures

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I'm using `addFeatures` in the REST API to add data to my table and it's working great. However... one of the fields in my data is a Related Record. I can query the Related Record fine using `queryRelatedRecords`, but Is there some way I can add related records via `addFeatures`? There doesn't seem to be an `addRelatedRecords` entrypoint. Here's what I would pass to `addFeatures` in my dream world...

```
$ev = (object)[
    'attributes' => (object)[
        'EVENTNAME' => 'test',
        'eventlocations' => list_of_locations_somehow?
    ],
];
```

Comment: (Without pulling up the REST doc, I think:) Your related records are probably just a table in the same service, so you'd call addFeature on that resource. So your workflow would be 2 addFeatures on the respective layer/table

Comment: Thank you for looking - do you know how I'd go about associating the new records in my event locations table with this related record in my original table?

Comment: You'd need to essentially follow the rules of your relationship. Meaning that on both addFeature calls you'd need to set the matching values in the established join field. (Again, I'm making some untested assumptions)